# Multiple SimpleActionServer member variables

Tags: ros, c++, action, actionlib, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a AI module for a robot. The module will provide two actions, so I've been learning about actionlib through the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials).

I implemented the [first tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29) and got it working nicely in my application.

My current approach for one action is roughly as follows. The action server is started in the class constructor.

```
class RobotAI
{
public:
    RobotAI(std::string name);
    ~RobotAI(void);
    void executeInspectAreaCB(const robot_ai::InspectAreaGoalConstPtr &goal);

private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;

    // Action servers and messages that are used to published feedback/result
    actionlib::SimpleActionServer<robot_ai::InspectAreaAction> inspect_as_; 
    std::string inspect_action_name_;
    robot_ai::InspectAreaFeedback inspect_feedback_;
    robot_ai::InspectAreaResult inspect_result_;
};
```

However, now that I'm implementing *two* actions and I would like to manage them within a single robot AI class, I was wondering what would be the best way of achieving this? Should I just add another `SimpleActionServer` to my current class to handle the other action? Or should I make a class as implemented in the first tutorial for both actions and include them as member variables for my AI class?

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221108/multiple-simpleactionserver-member-variables/) by [mikkola](https://answers.ros.org/users/25113/mikkola/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Should I just add another SimpleActionServer to my current class to handle the other action?

Yes.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikkola](https://answers.ros.org/users/25113/mikkola/) on 2015-11-19**:
Well, after scratching my head for a while before realising the two servers can't have the same name (d'oh), this works great! Thank you very much.